# How to read the note value in the score?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, midi

I am doing something like reading the MIDI info. Currently, I just read the onset and offset from `PrettyMIDI`. However, I found that the onset and offset is not really accurate(i hope it shows somthing like 1, 2.5, 3,4,6). It goes with something like 1,43, 2.34. Like this
[image]

So I am wondering how to read the exact note value.
For example, my expected result is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,]` in this image.
[image]

This is my current code.

```py
import os
import sys

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
from matplotlib import colors
import pretty_midi
import pandas as pd
import IPython.display as ipd
sys.path.append('..')
# import libfmp.c1

fn = os.path.join('..', 'data', 'C1', "Canon_in_D__Violin_Solo_.mid")
midi_data = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI(fn)
midi_list = []

for instrument in midi_data.instruments:
    for note in instrument.notes:
        start = note.start
        end = note.end
        pitch = note.pitch
        velocity = note.velocity
        midi_list.append([start, end, pitch, velocity])
        
midi_list = sorted(midi_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))

df = pd.DataFrame(midi_list, columns=['Start', 'End', 'Pitch', 'Velocity'])
html = df.to_html(index=True)
ipd.HTML(html)
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you provide your script in your question?

Comment: I don't know about the music. But is "the exact note value" in your question a pitch of note?

Comment: @ConstantinHong Neither of them. Note value indicates the relative duration of a note

Comment: How do you make or calculate an element of the last list `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,]`? What term is it called? I tried to understand it by myself, but the document of the PrettyMIDI library is not that specific for me.

Comment: @ConstantinHong Yah, that's what I am asking for. I think it called "note value" 
sad, hope others can help me.